# How can I make my plot look something like on the right side?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot some graph, here's my code

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,25)),aes(x=x))+
stat_function(fun=function(x){(18-6*x)/4},aes(color="Function 1"))+
stat_function(fun=function(x){(24-4*x)/3},aes(color="Function 2"))+
stat_function(fun=function(x){(20-10*x)/2},aes(color="Function 3"))+
theme_bw()+
scale_color_discrete(name="Function")+
geom_polygon(data=data.frame(x=c(0,3,Inf,3),y=c(4.5,0,Inf,Inf)),
             aes(x=x,y=y,fill="Constraint 1"),inherit.aes=F,alpha=0.4)+
scale_fill_discrete(name="Constraint Set")+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10.5))+
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,7))
```

And the result I got is this..

[image]
And this is the output that I wanted..
[image]

Comment: The polygon you want has six vertices (some of which are at infinity) but you are only specifying four vertices in your plot.

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to specify 6 points, it's just I don't get how to specify the other two.. :(

Comment: Simple algebra: the lines y = a1 + b1 * x and y = a2 + b2 * x intersect where a1 + b1 * x = a2 + b2 * x or when a1 - a2 = (b2 - b1) * x or x = (a1 - a2) /(b2 - b1).  Then get the y co-ordinate by substitution.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know from the pictures exactly which area you want shaded. It looks as though you want the area above Function 1 shaded. In which case, it's

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,25)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = ~(18 - 6 * .x)/4, aes(color = "Function 1")) +
  stat_function(fun = ~(24 - 4 * .x)/3, aes(color = "Function 2")) +
  stat_function(fun = ~(20 - 10 * .x)/2, aes(color = "Function 3")) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Function") +
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 3, Inf, Inf, 0),
                                 y = c(Inf, 4.5, 0, 0, Inf, Inf)),
               aes(x = x, y = y, fill = "Constraint 1"),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Constraint Set") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 7))
```

[image]

If you want the shaded area to be above the lines Function 2 and Function 3, then it's

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,25)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = ~(18 - 6 * .x)/4, aes(color = "Function 1")) +
  stat_function(fun = ~(24 - 4 * .x)/3, aes(color = "Function 2")) +
  stat_function(fun = ~(20 - 10 * .x)/2, aes(color = "Function 3")) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Function") +
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 6/11, 6, Inf, Inf, 0),
                                 y = c(Inf, 10, (24 - 4 * (6/11))/3,
                                       0, 0, Inf, Inf)),
               aes(x = x, y = y, fill = "Constraint 1"),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Constraint Set") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 7))
```

[image]

Which can be found using simple algebra.